# avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Permission denied Upload error:

Tags: arduino-ide, uploading, arduino-micro, linux

I am using `arduino-ide`2.0.0-beta.7(CLI Version:0.18.3 alpha) on Manjaro Linux and I get this error when uploading sketch to my Arduino Micro:

> avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Permission denied
> Upload error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: uploading error: uploading error: exit status 1

I checked other questions and tried:

```
sudo groupadd dialout
sudo gpasswd -a $USER dialout
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER  
sudo chown root:dialout -R /dev/
ls -l /dev/ttyACM0 #can see the root:dialout
```

But when I logout and get again after `ls -l /dev/ttyACM0`:

> crw-rw-rw- 1 root uucp 166, 0  6月 13 17:06 /dev/ttyACM0

So I cannot upload the sketch. Note: I can upload sketches using `sudo arduino-ide --no-sandbox` , but I want to upload them from the `user` account.

What else can I try?

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Linux#please-read

Comment: @Juraj I had to run ``sudo usermod -a -G uucp $USER `` instead of ``sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER``. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

I had to run:

```
sudo usermod -a -G uucp $USER
```

Thanks to @Juraj I realized that. Thanks @Juraj.